# Monitoring Amazon SageMaker NoteBook Instances Start and Stop Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, cpu-usage, amazon-sagemaker

We have created multiple SageMaker NoteBook instances, and would like to monitor the number of times NoteBook Instance were Started and Stopped along with the duration for which it was in-use and not in-use. How can I extract these details?

Answer (score 2):

SageMaker events are logged in CloudTrail. You could build a custom solution that listens for the [StartNotebookInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_StartNotebookInstance.html) and [StopNotebookInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_StopNotebookInstance.html) events, and writes the details to a persistent storage (e.g., DynamoDB) and run scripts periodically to calculate the duration and present in a dashboard. See [Log Amazon SageMaker API Calls with AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html), and this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html) to run Lambda functions on a schedule.

If you simply wanted to list running notebooks, you can [ListNotebookInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ListNotebookInstances.html) and filter by the status. Make sure to use the Pagintor since you mentioned multiple NBIs. This call does return the time created and last modified, but does not persist the previous start and stop times.